# How do I capture the keyboard enter/spacebar keydown events for an accordion structure with div and span elements

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make the accordions on our site accessible by adding support for keyboard control. I need to have the enter key or the spacebar key trigger the opening/closing of the accordions. The accordions are made up of div and span elements.

I've tried to adapt the current js code that works for a click with our accordions but can't get it to work.

Here is an example of the HTML for one accordion element on ours site:

`
Weddings, Private Events, and Space Rental

Header for Weddings

Wedding Rental Content

`

Here is the js that works for click event:
      `$('.accordion .title').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children('.content').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')){
            $(this).parent().attr("aria-expanded","true");
        }else {
            $(this).parent().attr("aria-expanded","false");
        }
    });`

Below is what I tried to do to reproduce this for a keypress on the Enter key, this doesn't work. Nothing happens.

```
  `$('.accordion .title').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('.accordion .title').click();
    }
  });`
```

When I change this code to point the jquery selector to one individual accordion node (with an id in the selector like $('#trigWeddings')), the code kind of works but opens all of the accordion nodes on the page which is obviously not what I want.

I'm confused about what I'm actually doing here, am I adding an event listener, and if not do I need to do that? How can I trigger what already exists for the click event for the keypress of the Enter or Spacebar key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$('.accordion .title').click();` is a too common selector, restrict it to `$(this).find('.title')` otherwise you'll target every single `.accordion` in the DOM
- Test using `RegExp.test()` for the `Event.which` is `32` or `13`
- If the above test passes, don't forget to use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser doing funkystufff on Spacebar press
- Use jQuery's `.closest()` and `.find()` to be more flexible with your DOM structure that might get changed in the future

```js
$('.accordion .title').click(function() {
  const $acc = $(this).closest('.accordion'); 
  $acc.find('.content').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $acc.attr("aria-expanded", $(this).hasClass('open'));
});

$('.accordion').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (/^(13|32)$/.test(e.which)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.title').click();
  }
});
```

```css
.content {display:none;}
```

```html
CLICK HERE, than TAB into DIV and hit enter or spacebar
<hr>
<div tabindex=0 class="accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sectWeddings" id="trigWeddings">
  <span class="title">Weddings, Private Events, and Space Rental</span>
  <div class="content" role="region" id="sectWeddings" aria-labledby="trigWeddings">
    <h4>Header for Weddings</h4>
    <p>Wedding Rental Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for your help and your excellent explanation for it all.